# ¿Por qué es erróneo siempre usar “while ( !feof (file) )”?

Tags: c, archivo, while

*Traducido desde: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong*

---

He visto mucha gente intentando leer archivos de esta forma ultimamente.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char * path = ( argc > 1 ) ? argv[1] : "input.txt";

    FILE * fp = fopen ( path, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror ( path );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while( !feof ( fp ) )  /* --ESTO ESTÁ MAL-- */
    {
        /* Lee y procesa datos desde el archivo… */
    }

    if( fclose ( fp ) == 0 )
    {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        perror(path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal con el bucle `while( !feof ( fp ) )`?

Comment: Sí lo revisaste [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) sabes que tienes muy buena fuente de información, **¿Por qué lo preguntas de nuevo?**

Comment: Creo que se trata de una pregunta auto-respondida para hacer disponible en español esta información.

Comment: Efectivamente, la idea es traducir esa información al español, para así disponerla cuando haga falta

Comment: +1 por la pregunta y la respuesta. Solo una pequeña sugerencia: deberías incluir la etiqueta `c++` ya que por diversas razones mucha gente escribe código en C++ como si fuese C y por ende creo que vendría bien que está información este disponible para los que trabajan con C++.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Traducido desde: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/8607301*

Me gustaría dar una perspectiva abstracta, de alto nivel.

#### Concurrencia y simultaneidad

Las operaciones E/S interactúan con el entorno. El entorno no forma parte de tu programa y no está bajo tu control. El entorno existe de forma verdaderamente "concurrente" con tu programa. Como con todas las cosas concurrentes, las preguntas sobre el "estado actual", simplemente no tienen sentido. No existe el concepto de "simultaneidad" en eventos concurrentes. Muchas de las propiedades de un estado, sencillamente, no *existen* de forma concurrente.

Precisemos un poco más: Supongamos que quieres preguntar "¿tienes más datos?". Podrías preguntárselo a un contenedor concurrente o a tu gestor de E/S de tu sistema. Pero la respuesta, de forma general, es inaccesible o, por tanto, simplemente no tiene sentido.
Así que si el contenedor dice que "sí", podría no tener los datos mientras estás leyendo. De forma similar, si la respuesta es "no", justo cuando estés leyendo, podrían los datos llegar. La conclusión a esto de forma simple es que no hay una propiedad tal como "tengo datos", ya que no puedes actuar de manera significativa en respuesta a cualquier situación posible. (La situación es ligeramente mejor con la entrada almacenada en búfer, donde posiblemente pueda obtener un "sí, tengo datos", que constituye algún tipo de garantía, pero aún tendría que ser capaz de lidiar con el caso opuesto. Y con el resultado, la situación ciertamente es tan mala como la describí: nunca se sabe si el disco o el búfer de red están llenos.)

Entonces, llegamos a la conclusión de que es imposible, y de hecho ir*razonable*, preguntar a un sistema de E/S si *podrá* realizar una operación de E/S. La única manera posible de interactuar con él (al igual que con un contenedor concurrente) es *intentar* la operación y verificar si se realizó correctamente o no. En ese momento en el que interactúa con el entorno, solo entonces podrá saber si la interacción fue realmente posible, y en ese momento debe comprometerse a realizar la interacción. (Esto es un "punto de sincronización", si lo desea).

#### EOF

Ahora llegamos a EOF. EOF es la *respuesta* que obtiene un *intento* operación de E/S. Significa que estaba intentando leer o escribir algo, pero al hacerlo no pudo leer o escribir ningún dato, y en su lugar se encontró el final de la entrada o salida. Esto es cierto para prácticamente todas las API de E/S, ya sea la biblioteca estándar de C, iostreams de C++ u otras bibliotecas. Mientras las operaciones de E/S tengan éxito, simplemente *no puede saber* si más adelante, las operaciones futuras tendrán éxito. *Debes* siempre primero probar la operación y luego responder al éxito o al fracaso.

#### Ejemplos

En cada uno de los ejemplos, hay que tener en cuenta que *primero* intentamos la operación de E/S y *luego* consumimos el resultado si es válido. También hay que tener en cuenta que *siempre* debemos usar el resultado de la operación de E/S, aunque en cada ejemplo el resultado tome diferentes aspectos y formas.

- Leer desde un archivo usando *stdio*, en C:

  ```
  for (;;) {
      size_t n = fread(buf, 1, bufsize, infile);
      consume(buf, n);
      if (n < bufsize) { break; }
  }
  ```

  El resultado que debemos usar es `n`, el número de elementos que acabamos de leer (el cual puede ser tan pequeño como cero).
- C stdio, `scanf`:

  ```
  for (int a, b, c; scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3; ) {
      consume(a, b, c);
  }
  ```

  El resultado que debemos usar es el valor que devuelve `scanf`, el número de elementos convertidos.
- Extracción con formato de iostreams, C++:

  ```
  for (int n; std::cin >> n; ) {
      consume(n);
  }
  ```

  El resultado que debemos usar es `std::cin` en sí mismo, ya que puede ser evaluado en un contexto booleano y nos diga si el flujo todavía está en `buen()` estado.
- C++, getline en iostreams:

  ```
  for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
      consume(line);
  }
  ```

  El resultado que debemos usar es el mismo de antes, `std::cin`.
- POSIX, usar `write(2)` para vaciar un búfer:

  ```
  char const * p = buf;
  ssize_t n = bufsize;
  for (ssize_t k = bufsize; (k = write(fd, p, n)) > 0; p += k, n -= k) {}
  if (n != 0) { /* error, failed to write complete buffer */ }
  ```

  El resultado que usamos aquí es `k`, el número de bytes escritos. La idea aquí es que podamos saber cuántos bytes han sido escritos *después* de la operación de escritura.
- POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

  ```
  char *buffer = NULL;
  size_t bufsiz = 0;
  ssize_t nbytes;
  while ((nbytes = getline(&buffer, &bufsiz, fp)) != -1)
  {
      /* Use nbytes of data in buffer */
  }
  free(buffer);
  ```

  El resultado que debemos usar es `nbytes`, el número de bytes que tenemos incluyendo el propio carácter de nueva línea (o EOF si el archivo no termina con un carácter de nueva línea).

  Nótese que esta función devuelve explícitamente `-1` **(y no EOF!)** cuando ocurre un error o cuando alcanza EOF.

Como puedes notar, muy rara vez decimos la palabra "EOF". Por lo general, detectamos la condición de error de alguna otra manera que es lo más interesante para nosotros inmediatamente (por ejemplo, no realizar la E/S que deseábamos). En cada ejemplo, hay una característica de la API que podría decirnos explícitamente que se ha encontrado el estado EOF, pero, de hecho, no es una información muy útil. Ese detalle es mucho más de lo que a menudo nos importa. Y nos importa si la E/S tuvo éxito, más que si falló.

- Un último ejemplo que realmente consulta el estado EOF: suponga que tiene una cadena y desea probar que representa un entero en su totalidad, sin bits adicionales al final, excepto los espacios en blanco. Usando iostreams de C++, es así:

  ```
  std::string input = "   123   ";   // example

  std::istringstream iss(input);
  int value;
  if (iss >> value >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF) {
      consume(value);
  } else {
      // error, "input" is not parsable as an integer
  }
  ```

  Usamos dos resultados aquí. El primero es `iss`, el objeto stream en sí mismo, para verificar que la extracción formateada a `value` haya tenido éxito. Pero luego, después de consumir los espacios en blanco, realizamos otra operación de E/S, `iss.get()` y esperamos que falle como EOF, que es el caso si la extracción con formato ya ha consumido toda la cadena.

  En la biblioteca estándar de C, puede lograr algo similar con las funciones `strto*l` comprobando que el puntero final haya llegado al final de la cadena de entrada.

#### La respuesta

`while(!eof)` es incorrecto porque prueba algo que es irrelevante y no prueba algo que necesitas saber. El resultado es que está ejecutando erróneamente un código que asume que está accediendo a datos que se leyeron con éxito, cuando, de hecho, en realidad nunca sucedió.