# Manejo de archivos en C con estructura de datos

Tags: c

Hola soy nuevo en C y tengo una duda con respecto al siguiente código. Estoy simulando un cajero automático bastante simple y las cuentas con nombre y balance están en el archivo llamado "cuentas.txt", todos los datos los pasé a una estructura de datos dinámica. Todo funciona correctamente pero solo funciona una vez, no estoy seguro si tiene que ver con los punteros o algo así. Me podrían ayudar con esto porfavor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(){
    typedef struct{
        char *numcuenta;
        char *nombre;
        char *apellido;
        float saldo;
    }cuentas;

    cuentas *cuenta;
    char aux;
    int n;
    int i;
    int j;
    int h;
    char temp[300];
    int cont = 0;
    int c;
    char ingresar;
    int transacciones;
    char numerocuenta[50];
    int condicion;
    int cond_existe;
    int cond;
    int posicion;
    float retiro;
    float deposito;

    c = 0;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("cuentas.txt", "r");
    rewind(f);
    if (f==NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(f)){
        fgets(temp,300,f);
        cont++;
    }
    rewind(f);

    cuenta = (cuentas*)malloc(cont*sizeof(cuentas));
    if(cuenta == NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria\n");
    }

    for (h=0 ; !feof(f); h++){
        for(i=0 ; i<300 ; i++){
            temp[i] = '\0';
        }
        aux = '0';
        for (j = 0; aux!=','; j++){
            aux = fgetc(f);
            if (aux != ','){
                temp[j] = aux;
            }
        }
        n = strlen(temp)+1;
        cuenta[h].numcuenta = (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        if (cuenta[h].numcuenta == NULL){
            printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(cuenta[h].numcuenta,temp);

        aux = '0';
        for (j = 0; aux!=','; j++){
            aux = fgetc(f);
            if (aux != ','){
                temp[j] = aux;
            }
        }
        n = strlen(temp)+1;
        cuenta[h].nombre = (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        if (cuenta[h].nombre == NULL){
            printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(cuenta[h].nombre,temp);

        aux = '0';
        for (j=0; aux != ','; j++){
            aux = fgetc(f);
            if (aux != ','){
                temp[j] = aux;
            }
        }
        n = strlen(temp)+1;
        cuenta[h].apellido = (char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        if (cuenta[h].apellido == NULL){
            printf("No se ha podido reservar la memoria\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(cuenta[h].apellido,temp);

        fgets(temp,300,f);
        cuenta[h].saldo = atoi(temp);

        printf("Numero de cuenta: %s   Nombre: %s   Apellido: %s   Saldo %f\n",cuenta[h].numcuenta,cuenta[h].nombre,cuenta[h].apellido,cuenta[h].saldo);
        c++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    condicion = 1;
    cond = 1;

    printf("\n\t\t\tBienvenido al banco Galileo \n Por favor inserte la tarjeta ('t' para ingresar la tarjeta)\n");
    scanf("%c",&ingresar);
    fflush(stdin);
    while (ingresar != 't'){
        printf("\t\t\tBienvenido al banco Galileo. \n Por favor inserte la tarjeta ('t' para ingresar la tarjeta)\n");
        scanf("%c",&ingresar);
        fflush(stdin);
    }


    do{
        printf("Porfavor ingrese su numero de cuenta, asegurese que la cuenta tenga 5 digitos y que sean solo numeros\n");
        scanf("%s",numerocuenta);
        for (i=0;i<c;i++) {
            cond_existe = strcmp(cuenta[i].numcuenta, numerocuenta);
            if (cond_existe == 0) {
                posicion = i;
                printf("Cuenta registrada, bienvenid@ %s %s\n", cuenta[i].nombre, cuenta[i].apellido);
                condicion = 0;
            }
        }
    }while(condicion == 1);


    while (cond == 1){
        printf("¿Que desea hacer?\n");
        printf("1. Retiro\n2. Deposito\n3. Consulta de Saldo\n4. Salida del Sistema\n\n");
        scanf("%i",&transacciones);
        switch (transacciones) {
            case 1:
                printf("Ingrese la cantidad que desea retirar\n");
                scanf("%f",&retiro);
                if (retiro > cuenta[posicion].saldo){
                    printf("La cantidad a retirar es mayor al saldo disponible en la cuenta\n\n");
                    break;
                }else{
                    cuenta[posicion].saldo = cuenta[posicion].saldo - retiro;
                    printf("%f\n\n",cuenta[posicion].saldo);
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                printf("Ingrese la cantidad que desea depositar\n");
                scanf("%f",&deposito);
                cuenta[posicion].saldo = cuenta[posicion].saldo + deposito;
                printf("%f han sido depositados\n\n",deposito);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Su saldo actual es de ");
                printf("%f\n\n",cuenta[posicion].saldo);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Su sesion ha sido terminada con exito, no olvide retirar su tarjeta");
                cond = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Porfavor ingrese una de las opciones listadas\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    FILE *g;
    g = fopen("cuentas.txt","w");
    rewind(g);
    for (i=0; i<c; i++){
        fprintf(f,"%s,%s,%s,%f\n",cuenta[i].numcuenta,cuenta[i].nombre,cuenta[i].apellido,cuenta[i].saldo);
    }
    fclose(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el código y como mencioné antes no se si tiene que ver algo que ver con los punteros del archivo llamado "cuentas.txt", al final lo volví a abrir para reemplazar el saldo de la cuenta y que cuando se vuelva a ejecutar tenga el nuevo saldo y al volver a ejecutarlo que lea los nuevos datos. Cuando intento compilar otra vez solo me sale esto
Process finished with exit code 0xc0000005
y ya no logro hacer que funcione otra vez

Comment: Cuando, dices *Todo funciona correctamente pero solo funciona una vez, no estoy seguro si tiene que ver con los punteros o algo así* la información que das es vaga. ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona según esperas? ¿Has probado a depurar tu código y ejecutarlo paso a paso para ver qué es lo que falla?

Comment: Da, por favor, una mirada a [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: El problema comienza aquí `aux = fgetc(f);`, no verificas que llegaste al final del fichero (`EOF`), por eso al llegar a `temp[j] = aux;` invades memoria que no es tuya. Cuando *«grabas»* el fichero añades una línea en blanco y el problema se revela.

Comment: (1) [`while(!feof(f))`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212886/por-qu%c3%a9-es-err%c3%b3neo-siempre-usar-while-feof-file). (2) `fflush(stdin)` está mal, fflush puede limpiar solo un búfer de salida, no un búfer de ingreso. (3) divide tu programa en funciones, es ilegible.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a liberar la memoria que reservas con `malloc`? Para ello emplea la función `free` ([info aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm)) cuando vayas a salir del programa o no vayas a utilizar más la información almacenada en la memoria dinámica que has creado.